# How does find -name work?

Tags: find, regular-expression

I can't for the life of me figure out how `find` with the test `-name` works.

I run `find / -name *in` and returns a bunch of results:

```
/sbin
/sbin/sulogin
/dev/stdin
```

to name a few.

It's as if it performed filename expansion, but that happens before the shell runs the command, so that can't be it. Also because I don't have any files in the current directory that match `*in`. Plus, single quoting `*in` yields the same results, which further supports that this can't be filename expansion.

The documentation leads me to believe that `find` with `-name` uses regular expressions, but the regex pattern `*in` doesn't match the results I showed above.

Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: "It's as if it performed filename expansion, but that happens before the shell runs the command, so that can't be it." But that's exactly what it is! Only that instead of matching the `*in` pattern against the files from the cwd, it matches it against the the files from the directories it's walking through.

Comment: "The documentation kind of suggests that find with -name uses regular expressions" the documentation does not suggest such thing.

Comment: @mosvy I edited my question.

Comment: If you need regular expressions, you can use `-regex pattern` which is used to match the whole path (including slashes), while `-name pattern` operates on the filename and uses shell patterns.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The parameter passed to `-name` is a filesystem *glob* pattern, the same as the you'd enter for other commands, such as `ls -l *in`.

For each file it finds it compares the *basename* of the file to the pattern you passed.  So when it finds `/bin/foobar` it compares `foobar` to `*in`, doesn't match, skips; but with `/bin/login` it compares `login` to `*in` and this does match, and so prints.

Now you need to be careful because `*in` might be matched on the command line depending on files in the current directory.

So, for example:

```
$ find /bin -name *in
/bin
/bin/login

$ touch foobarin

$ find /bin -name *in
$
```

Notice the same `find` command returned two different results.

We can see why if we set the shell to debug mode:

```
$ rm foobarin 

$ set -x

$ find /bin -name *in
+ find /bin -name '*in'
/bin
/bin/login

$ touch foobarin     
+ touch foobarin

$ find /bin -name *in
+ find /bin -name foobarin

$
```

The lines starting with a `+` are what the shell interpreted the command entered.  We can see that the second `find` command expanded the `*in` to match the existing filename.

Because of this it's recommended to *quote* names

```
$ find /bin -name '*in'
+ find /bin -name '*in'
/bin
/bin/login
```

Comment: Thank you, that's helpful. When you say that we should quote names. Should it be, more precisely, single quote them?

Comment: The quote will depend on how you want the command line to interpret your input, same as everywhere else.  So if you're looking for a file called `$foo` then you may use `'$foo'` but if you want to expand the _variable_ then you may use `"$foo"`.   This isn't specific to the `find` command, but is how the command line works.

Comment: But won't the variable be expanded just like `*` was when you used single quotes? EDIT: I understand this expansion occurs after the command is ran, contrarily to "regular expansion".

Comment: No; command line globs don't follow variable expansion.  eg  if we set `$ foo='*in'` then the command `$ find /bin -name "$foo"` will give the debug output `+ find /bin -name '*in'` which is exactly what we want.